# Meaning of Quotient in this context

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations

I was seeing the following problem a couple days ago:
Let $R \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ denote the unit square $R = [0,1] \times [0,1]$. If $F \subset R$ is finite, is $R \backslash F$ connected?

I understand $R\backslash F$ in the case where F is an equivalence relation but in this it does not seem like it. Can someone explain this to me in a intuitive way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R\setminus F$ is just a square without finite number of points. It seems to be connected, because each two points of $R\setminus F$ can be easily connected by a broken line consisting of two segments.

Comment: I think the OP is using \ as a quotient, from the rest of the text; it is definitely not common usage. I was also confused at first, but I think that's the way he's using it.

Comment: This is not from my text but something I saw online and I related it t the quotient instead of the exclusion! How dumb can I be?!

Answer (score 0):

No; the image will always be connected (in the quotient topology), because a quotient map is , by construction/definition continuous, and the continuous image of a connected space 
(here the unit square) is always connected.